# Scrollbar on demand in CSS (overflow property)

Tags: html, css

I am creating a `<div>` with a class `someClass`

```
.someClass {
   overflow:scroll
   /*other props*/
}
```

The problem is that the scrollbars are always visible even when the data is not overflowing. I want the scrollbars to be visible only when data actually overflows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`overflow:auto;` should do it. You need to set a width (for horizontal scrolling) and height (vertical) for that to pop out scrollbars at the right time though.

Answer (score 3):

Use `overflow: auto;`